# How to access a repository from another computer using Tortoise svn?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I was install tortoise SVN in my system and i want to give a checkout to my friend so he needs to access my repository like 192.168.10.24/reponame/ so how he can checkout.

The repository is not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share your repository with another person you need to set up a Subversion **server**. TortoiseSVN is not a server, it's only a client. Your server will need to be accessible to your friend via network, so unless he's on the same network as you are, you'll need to open a port on your firewall, forward the traffic through, and pay attention to all the security concerns that come with operating a server on the Internet.

Or you could try Git, create a repository on Github, tell him where to find it, and have him send you pull requests when he wants to integrate his work with yours. Or try Bitbucket (with Mercurial or Git) - pretty much the same principle, difference being that Bitbucket is free private repositories and Github charges for private repos. You won't have to worry about the networking, server operation, backups, security or anything else related.

Comment: i just want to put all my codes in my network. Rabbit svn like subversion. only code will be present in two system and both of them work and commit. it ll show conflict if have. Can you imagine my problem ?

Comment: Can i use Git for it ?

Comment: You can, but you'll still have the same issues that you're having now - the need to run a server, open your network so your friend can get to it, etc. Unless your friend is on the same network as you, which you have failed to specify.

Comment: tortoise svn and visual svn server is helpful?

Comment: No. Is your friend on your network or is he going to be accessing it remotely, across the internet?

Comment: ya i got it by using visual svn and tortoise svn